# Wrong filling of Median replacing of Null values in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, median

lets say i have a dataset like below:
[image]

I want to replace the null values with the median of each column. But when I am trying to do that all NA is replaced with the median of the first column only.

```
Rough_df = pd.read_excel(r'Cleandata_withOutliers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
Rough_df.fillna(Rough_df.select_dtypes(include='number').median().iloc[0], inplace=True)
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

But, ideally, the NA values in the 2nd column should be replaced with 10170.5 and not with 77.5. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Rough_df.select_dtypes(include='number').median()` will give you a series with the medians of each column. Then when you index it with `.iloc[0]` it takes only the first value, the median of the first column, and then you use that value to `fillna()` on the whole dataframe

Comment: Ahh! that was the problem. I removed the indexing. Rough_df.fillna(Rough_df.select_dtypes(include='number').median(), inplace=True), Now it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do `median` with `fillna`

```
out = df.fillna(df.median())
Out[68]: 
       X        Y
0   60.0   9550.0
1   85.0  10170.5
2   77.5  10791.0
3  101.0  14215.0
4   47.0  16321.0
5  108.0  10170.5
6   77.5   8658.0
7   70.0   7945.0
```